# android webview freezes after fb.login() function called

Tags: javascript, android, facebook

I have a webpage which imports facebook javascript sdk.

When I tried to access this webpage from the web, no errors occurred and the facebook login process

was smoothly done. However, when I tried to use FB.login function from the android webview,

the webview freezed after login page. It looks like sending my id and password info to facebook can

be done without problem.

but the problem is that I am not ever getting a response back from facebook.

[image]

below is the log from android logcat after clicking the login button.

[image]

According to the log, facebook received my request but it doesn't seem like it is sending any response.

Has anybody tried to access webpage using javascript sdk from android webview?

Has anyone else faced the same problem as me? How did you guys handle it?

javascript sdk login process in android webview?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem! Found a bug report on the Facebook site but there is no response there... Found a solution?

For now, my only solution seems handling it with Php Facebook SDK and use the same window (I think the problem occurs when trying to autoclose the login-tab...)

Comment: no... still cant find any decent solution yet. It looks like oauth dialog works on android webkit. Although it redirects to ugly desktop facebook login page, at least it does not freezes android webview. But this is not what I wanted... I need to find out other solutions.